# How to add bootstrap popover to angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have `angular ng-repeat`:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-class="getClassForEmployee(employee.redRow)" >
    <td>{{employee.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.departmentName}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.dateContractEnd}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="#employeeCorrect/{{employee.id}}">Редактировать</a></td>
</tr>
```

And JS code in AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.getClassForEmployee = function (employeeRedRow) {
    if (employeeRedRow) {
        return "alert alert-danger";
    }
};
```

I want to add bootstrap popover to **red** `<tr>`. For example:

```
 <tr id="popover" data-content="something" title="something">
```

And initialize popover:

```
$("tr[id=popover]").popover({placement:"top",trigger:"hover"});
```

How to dinamic add id, data-content and title to red rows?

Comment: use angular-ui bootstarp instead  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha ok. So how to add attribute `popover` to only **red** rows?

Comment: i added a answer with a plunker please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qhFDpZUsP1uCO2DjLD64?p=preview) by using angular-ui bootstrap :)

```
 .... popover="{{ (employee.redRow) ? employee.first_name : '' }}" ....
if employee.redRow is true we add firstname as the poop
else we pass nothing for the poop then its not gonna show the poop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use angular-ui or make simple wrapper

```
module.directive('jsPopover', [function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      params: '=jsPopover'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
      $element.popover($scope.params);

      $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $element.popover('destroy');
      });
    }
  } 
}]);
```